# Not able to post data from Form to Service

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, servicestack

I have created a bootstrap form in Razor View Page. I want to send the form data to a Service using Request DTO but its not happening. I am able to get the button click event to work, and the breakpoint is reaching to Service but with empty data.

Here is my Form Markup:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="~/User" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> First Name </label>
  <div class="col-sm-9"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my Service:

```
public object Post(RegisterUser registerUserRequest)
    {
        var newUserRegister = new RegisterUser()
        {
            FirstName = registerUserRequest.FirstName,
            LastName = registerUserRequest.LastName,
        }
    }
```

One more thing that I thought is worth sharing is that my Model class Contains more properties than what I have displaye, however I dont think they matter in this case. Please help me resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough details on which route the `RegisterUser` is hosted. You should also provide the HTTP Request and Response Headers which provides the best source of info on what the issue is.

You also shouldn't use `~/` prefix which doesn't do anything in ServiceStack, you can instead use the Request DTO [Reverse Routing extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing) to get a Typed API on the URL you want to post, e.g:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" 
      action="@(new RegisterUser().ToPostUrl())" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> 
      First Name </label>
  <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

ServiceStack also encourages you to use an API First Development approach which encourages you to use [Ajax Bootstrap Forms](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#bootstrap-forms) which will send your forms using Ajax and auto bind any error or validation error responses to your form error placeholders, which you can call with:

```
$("form").bindForm({
    success: function(response) { }
});
```

The [Email Contacts](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts) demo is a good example that includes a walk through explaining how this works. There's additional info in the [docs on ss-utils.js](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ss-utils.js-JavaScript-Client-Library)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and suggestion.My request URL is `Request URL:http://localhost:54990/RegisterUser` when i am seeing in chrome developer tool.The issue that i am seeing is that it is not posting Form data.Any reason for this in this case?

Comment: @Lara The HTML Form behavior is just basic web development, you should be adding `name=` on your Form INPUT fields.